# UIImage conversion from NSData

Tags: uiimage, nsdata

I am creating an app that takes a json and parse it in order to obtain various NSDictionary filled by NSString.
When I start to show all these data inside my table view, Name and Address work fine, but I can't show up images, I actually use this brunch of code:

```
NSLog (@" URL img --> %@" , [dict objectForKey:@"urlimgp"]);

p.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"urlimgp"]]]];

NSLog (@" IMG --> %@" , p.image);
```

I can't figure out why the output from the first NSLog shows the exact url (so i know everything works fine with sql and php), but in the second NSLog I have got a (null). I really thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is not being encoded with percent escape encoding using UTF-8..

```
NSString *urlStr = [dict objectForKey:@"urlimgp"];
urlStr = [urlStr stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
NSData *data = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease];
UIImage *image =[UIImage imageWithData:data];
```